# Android4.4以上でFileプラグインで画像へアクセスするとSecurityException

Tags: monaca

takahashiといいます。

monacaで開発をしています。
Android4.4以上の端末で以下の現象があります。

アプリ内からCameraプラグインのgetPicture()でギャラリーを起動します。
内部ストレージ（左側に縦に並んでいる箇所）から画像を選択し、画像サイズを取得しようとすると
SecurityExceptionが発生します。

```
E/DatabaseUtils(16641): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/9C33-6BBD:Download/ダウンロード.jpg from pid=7821, uid=10385 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:467)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:394)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:387)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:339)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:316)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
E/DatabaseUtils(16641):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

何か対応策があればご教授ください。

ちなみにQuickPikや別なギャラリーアプリを使うと上記の現象は発生しません。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに示されているよう[Android Manifest](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/config/android_configuration/)の`uses-permission`に`android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`を加えてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/> を追加してみたのですが、現象かわらずでした。

Comment: スタックトレースの内容も変わらず、ということですよね。ちなみにCordovaは2.9ではなく3.5or4.1(?)ですよね？......自分はmonacaユーザーではないのでお手伝いできるのはこの辺りまでになります......

Comment: Cordovaは4.1を使っています。

Answer (score -1):

http://blog.kotemaru.org/2014/11/23/android-choose-picture.html
同じ症状かもしれません。
見てみて下さい。